# Login page based on Audience manager is not working for dxa 1.5, web 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8.5, audience-manager, dxa-1.5

I am new to audience manager.
we have created a login page and registration page based on 'audience manager' where cms version is 8.5 and dxa version is 1.5 and .net version 4.5.2.

functionality and website code is working fine in dev and uat environment.
once same website code has been deployed to prod functionality has been broken.
on checking cd_client.log, we have found following error message:

```
2020-07-03 10:45:42 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Failed to load assembly 'Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.resources, Version=8.5.0.209, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b'. Check the versions present match this assembly.
2020-07-03 10:45:42 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
           at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
           at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
           at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.PublicationContext.GetPublicationIdFromAdf()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.PublicationContext.get_CurrentPublicationId()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.ExtendedDetails.LoadExtendedDetailStructureCache()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.ExtendedDetails.GetExtendedDetailsFromCache()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact.InitializeExtendedDetails()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact..ctor()
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.Areas.TMSCInteractive.Controllers.LoginController.RegisterUser(RegistrationModel model) in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 132
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.Areas.TMSCInteractive.Controllers.LoginController.Registration(RegistrationModel model, EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize) in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 114
           at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
           at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntity(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntities(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Int32 containerSize)
           at ASP._Page_Areas_TMSCInteractive_Views_Region_LoginContainer_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Staging\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Views\Region\LoginContainer.cshtml:line 3
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaRegion(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, RegionModel region, Int32 containerSize)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaRegions(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String exclude, Int32 containerSize)
           at ASP._Page_Areas_TMSCInteractive_Views_Page_InteractiveContentPage_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Staging\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Views\Page\InteractiveContentPage.cshtml:line 6
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
           at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
           at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
           at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
2020-07-03 10:45:42 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Failed to load assembly 'Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.resources, Version=8.5.0.209, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b'. Check the versions present match this assembly.
2020-07-03 10:45:42 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
           at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
           at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
           at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
           at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.PublicationContext.GetPublicationIdFromAdf()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.PublicationContext.get_CurrentPublicationId()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.ExtendedDetails.LoadExtendedDetailStructureCache()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.ExtendedDetails.GetExtendedDetailsFromCache()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact.InitializeExtendedDetails()
           at Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact..ctor()
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.Areas.TMSCInteractive.Controllers.LoginController.RegisterUser(RegistrationModel model) in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 132
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.Areas.TMSCInteractive.Controllers.LoginController.Registration(RegistrationModel model, EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize) in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 114
           at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
           at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntity(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntities(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Int32 containerSize)
           at ASP._Page_Areas_TMSCInteractive_Views_Region_LoginContainer_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Staging\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Views\Region\LoginContainer.cshtml:line 3
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
           at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
           at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaRegion(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, RegionModel region, Int32 containerSize)
           at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaRegions(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String exclude, Int32 containerSize)
           at ASP._Page_Areas_TMSCInteractive_Views_Page_InteractiveContentPage_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Staging\Areas\TMSCInteractive\Views\Page\InteractiveContentPage.cshtml:line 6
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
           at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
           at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
           at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
           at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
           at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

we have checked following:

> dll version present under bin is following: Sdl.AudienceManager.ContentDelivery.resources, Version=8.5.0.209.

> DLL is not blocked.

It will be helpful if you please can help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Stack Trace, there seem to be two problems:

1. Something goes wrong when AM tries to determine the Publication ID (`GetPublicationIdFromAdf`)
2. AM creates a localizable error message, but something goes wrong loading the string resources.

So, an error occurs in the error handling of the first problem.

Note that as of DXA 1.6, there is a DXA Audience Manager Module. This Module contains a work-around for an issue with AM resolving the Publication ID inside a DXA web app using SDL Web 8 CIL.

See method `UserProfileFactory.PreparePublicationResolving`: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.6/webapp-net/AudienceManager/UserProfileFactory.cs

However, this work-around was removed in DXA 1.7, because it uses CIL 8.5 and the work-around was not needed there anymore (note that DXA 1.5 uses CIL 8.2).

So, basically, DXA 1.5 is too old. If you’re on SDL Web 8.5, it is recommended to use at least DXA 1.7 (but you can also upgrade to the latest version: DXA 2.2).

If you’re upgrading to DXA 1.7 or higher, I would also recommend to consider using the DXA Audience Manager Module (which takes care of some of the integration complexity, as you can see above).

Comment: thank you for the information. let me tryout workaround option. DXA upgrade is also inplace which will take some more time. i will let you know the update.